# Javascript function invocation & binding

Tags: javascript, function, binding, method-invocation

I have the following part of code:

```js
var person = {
  name: "Brendan Eich",
  hello: function(thing) {
    console.log(this.name + " says hello " + thing);
  }
}

var bind = function(func, thisValue) {
  return function() {
    return func.apply(thisValue, arguments);
  }
}

var boundHello = bind(person.hello, person);
boundHello("world") // "Brendan Eich says hello world"
```

Here, the code will print out in the console the text

> Brendan Eich says hello world

if I take the bind variable assignment and I change it to:

```js
var person = {
  name: "Brendan Eich",
  hello: function(thing) {
    console.log(this.name + " says hello " + thing);
  }
}

var bind = function(func, thisValue) {
  return func.apply(thisValue, arguments);
}

var boundHello = bind(person.hello, person);
boundHello("world") // "Brendan Eich says hello world"
```

then the results is

> Brendan Eich says hello function(thing) {
>       console.log(this.name + " says hello " + thing);   }

Could someone explain me why is that happening and what exactly are the 2 nested *return* functions inside the *bind* one?

How exactly do they work?

Comment: When I run your second example, I get `uncaught TypeError: boundHello is not a function` - which is what I expected (but was checking it anyway in case I'd missed something). The difference is that the first (correct) version of `bind` returns a *function* - a version of `func` which is always bound to `thisValue` as its `this` reference. The second (incorrect) version just returns a (non-function) value straight away (in this case it's `undefined`, but it will in general be whatever `func` returns for the arguments you've supplied) - so you can't call it.

Comment: I think I slightly understand what you mean by non-function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to explain as best as I can. On the first example your `bind` definition is a `function` that get two arguments, ideally a **function** as **first argument** (lets call it **THE_FUNC**) and an **object** as **second argument** (lets call it **THE_THIS_ARG**) that will use as the `thisArgs` for that function.

Now, this `bind` definition returns a `function` that explicitly takes no arguments (but implicitly could take **any arguments**) and when this function is called it will return the evaluation of calling [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) on **THE_FUNC** using **THE_THIS_ARG** as the value of `this` for **THE_FUNC** and using the `arguments` received (lets call it **THE_ARGS**) as the arguments passed to **THE_FUNC**.

For your particular example, the setup will be this one:

**THE_FUNC** => `person.hello`

**THE_THIS_ARG** => `person`

**THE_ARGS** => `["world"]` (array-like object)

Finally `boundHello("word")` is then traduced in something like (not exactly) this:

```
person.hello.apply(person, ["world"]);
```

Maybe, next example with some debugs can help you to understand better than my explanation:

```js
var person = {
    name: "Brendan Eich",
    hello: function(thing)
    {
        console.log(this.name + " says hello " + thing);
    }
}

var bind = function(func, thisValue)
{
    console.log("func is: ", func);
    console.log("thisValue is: ", thisValue);
    return function()
    {
        console.log("Arguments are:", arguments);
        return func.apply(thisValue, arguments);
    }
}

var boundHello = bind(person.hello, person);
boundHello("world") // "Brendan Eich says hello world"
```

The same explanation is some sort of valid for the second example too. But in this case `bind` do not return a function like in the previous example, and instead call `apply` with this setup:

**THE_FUNC** => `person.hello`

**THE_THIS_ARG** => `person`

**THE_ARGS** => `[person.hello, person]` (array-like object)

So, when you call `bind(person.hello, person)` is then traduced into something like:

```
person.hello.apply(person, [person.hello, person]);
```

And as you can see `person.hello` will be the `thing` argument received by `person.hello()` method and that is the reason a function definition is printed in the place of the `thing` argument.

```js
var person = {
    name: "Brendan Eich",
    hello: function(thing)
    {
        console.log(this.name + " says hello " + thing);
    }
}
    
var bind = function(func, thisValue)
{
    console.log("Arguments are:", arguments);
    return func.apply(thisValue, arguments);
}

var boundHello = bind(person.hello, person);
//boundHello("world") // "Uncaught TypeError: boundHello is not a function"
```

Comment: Thanks! Console logging seems that it made the trick and helped me to understand!

Answer (score 3):

In your second version you're calling `func` when you call `bind()`, and returning the value of the function call.

It's printing the source code of the `hello` function because `arguments` is the array-like object `[person.hello, person]`, so you're effectively making the call `person.hello(person.hello, person)`, and this sets `thing` to `person.hello`, and converting a function to a string for the purpose of concatenation returns its source code.

To bind a function you have to return a closure that can be called later. That's done in your first version by returning an anonymous function.

Comment: One confusing part to me is that the returned function should have a parameter which right now it does not take any. Right? I am also guessing that I should read about Javascript closures...?

Comment: The returned function uses the special variable `arguments`, which is automatically set to an array of all the arguments given to the function. So it will work with any number of parameters.